# How to combine the results of two different queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that displays the total amount of matches won by individual teams in the database,

```sql
select t.name, count(*) 'Matches_Won' 
from test.team t 
inner join test.match_scores m on m.winner = t.id 
group by t.name 
order by Matches_Won desc;
```

Another query prints out the total number of Matches Won by the Individual Teams in the database,

```sql
select t.name, count(*) 'Matches_PLayed' 
from test.team t 
inner join test.match_scores m on m.home_team = t.id or m.away_team = t.id 
group by t.name
order by Matches_Played desc;
```

Now, I am trying to combine these two queries, I want a table with three columns,

1. Team Name
2. Matches Played
3. Matches Won

I tried to **union** the two queries, but it didn't work. Anyone who can guide me on this?

**EDIT: **

This is the **Team Table**

[image]

This is the **Match Scores Table**. In this table, the columns "Home Team", "Away Team" represents the Goals scored by respective team and the "Winner" is the foreign key, referring to the Team Table.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample of your table? and what version of MySQL you are using

Comment: @Ahmed I have added the samples of my two tables that I am using. As for the version, I believe I am using the latest SQL Version and I am working on SQL Workbench.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/)

Comment: For the second row, the home team is 7, the away team is 0 and the winner is 15, what does that mean? also do you have a team with 0 id?

Comment: @Ahmed No, I am sorry, I didn't explain the tables. The Home_Team, and Away_Team columns basically represent the scores of the respective teams. In the 2nd row, away team scored 0 goals, and home team scored 7 goals, the winner of the 2nd row was the team with ID = 15. No team has ID = 0. Akina, I am looking at the Conditional Aggregation, right now, thank you

Comment: In this case how could we know the total number of matches played per team, you are storing only the winnings !

Comment: @Ahmed Hmm, you are right. I have written the wrong query, Sorry for that. I will get it corrected and will post the question again. This involves another table. This should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to **join** the subqueries,

```
select
            w.name,
            w.Matches_Won,
            p.Matches_Played
    from
            (
            select
                        t.id,
                        count(*) 'Matches_PLayed' 
                from
                        test.team t 
                    inner join
                        test.match_scores m
                            on m.home_team = t.id or m.away_team = t.id 
                 group by
                        t.id
            ) p
        left join
            (
            select
                        t.id
                        t.name,
                        count(*) 'Matches_Won'
                from
                        test.team t
                   inner join
                        test.match_scores m
                            on m.winner = t.id
                group by
                        t.id
            ) w
                on w.id = p.id
    order by
            w.Matches_Won,
            p.Matches_Played
```

However, it would also be possible to combine these aggregations into one query...

```
select
            t.name,
            sum(case when m.winner = t.id then 1 else 0 end) 'Matches_Won'
            count(*) 'Matches_Played'
    from
            test.team t 
        inner join
            test.match_scores m
               on m.home_team = t.id or m.away_team = t.id
    group by
            t.id
    order by
            Matches_Won,
            Matches_Played
```

Comment: This is too complex.

Comment: this may slowly because you join via name field and if the team has not been winner, this query doesn't show lost matchs. this is not enough query

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    select t.name, (select count(*) from match_scores where winner = t.id) as 'Matches_Won', (select count(*) from match_scores where home_team = t.id or away_team=t.id) as 'Matches_PLayed'
from team t
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t.name, 
       SUM(m.winner = t.id) 'Matches_Won',
       SUM(t.id IN (m.home_team, m.away_team)) 'Matches_Played'
FROM test.team t 
CROSS JOIN test.match_scores m
GROUP BY t.name;
```